# Azure KQL: convert date in string format "20210820122039" to datetime in azure KQL

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a column in azure application insights which is string where date is stored as string in the format
**20210820122039** (yyyymmddhhmmss) I want to create new column which will be copy of the existing column by converting all values to date format (default format is fine). Can some one help me with API which helps to do this in Azure KQL.

Below is some information about data and query.

Json Data stored in custom dimensions. optional header is extracted from custom dimensions looks something like this.
{"UTCDate":"2021-08-20T08:41:28.0260000Z",,"Date":"20210820104125","isPresent":"False"}

I want Date value to be converted to datetime data type with default date format say yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Below is my KQL

```
traces
| extend optionalHeaders=todynamic(tostring(customDimensions.OptionalHeaders))
| extend DateMeta=todatetime(optionalHeaders.Date_metaData)
```

This is resulting in empty column also todatetime does not support passing format argument like this todatetime(optionalHeaders.Date_metaData,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss')

[image]

Comment: Just a wild question - why won't you use the UTC timestamp 'UTCData'  that is a) universal and b) already formatted correctly?

Answer (score 1):

```
let dt = datetime(20210820122039);
print 
dt
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Silent, Thanks for your reply. I have updated my question. I want to convert entire column which is string to any date format

Comment: well have you tried to use `datetime()` instead of `todatetime()`?

Comment: Yes i tried below is the query.    traces
| extend optionalHeaders=todynamic(tostring(customDimensions.OptionalHeaders))
| extend DateMeta=datetime(optionalHeaders.Date_metaData). I get below errors Query could not be parsed at 'datetime(optionalHeaders.Date_metaData)' on line [3,57]

Answer (score 1):

as this is an unsupported datetime format (see: [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/datetime#supported-formats)), you'll need to parse the datetime parts out of the value, then use [`make_datetime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-datetimefunction) to construct the datetime value:

```
print d = dynamic({"UTCDate":"2021-08-20T08:41:28.0260000Z","Date":"20210820104125","isPresent":"False"})
| project dt_str = tostring(d.Date)
| project result = make_datetime(
    toint(substring(dt_str, 0, 4)),
    toint(substring(dt_str, 4, 2)),
    toint(substring(dt_str, 6, 2)),
    toint(substring(dt_str, 8, 2)),
    toint(substring(dt_str, 10, 2)),
    toint(substring(dt_str, 12, 2)))
```

| result |
| --- |
| 2021-08-20 10:41:25.0000000 |

Answer (score 0):

FWIW you can also use this:
`| parse kind=regex flags=Uis Time with day "/" month "/" year " " hour ":" minute ":" second "." millisecond " " timezone "$"`
as an example to parse a timestring in the format `01/01/1970 00:01:00.000 +0100`